# Protect single url using htaccess, but without SetEnvIf

Tags: php, .htaccess, litespeed

I'm trying to protect a single url using htaccess password. (it's my admin page)

After some research, I found (on stackoverflow) the solution : use SetEnvIf to detect the URL and then ask password only when we have the URL.

I tested it but that didn't work : the password was asked everytime. After investigation with my host, it seems they are runnig LITESPEED (and not Apache) and the module SetEnvIf is not activated. As a result, I am stuck... Can I do it differently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always try doing it [manually with PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php). AFAIK no server configuration is necessary.

Comment: Not what I was thinking first (cause I didn't know about it) but after testing it seems nice and more flexible. THanks, I will use this.
Btw, is are htacess and php auth equally secured ?

Comment: Strictly speaking I'd say .htaccess files would be more secure, because that way your PHP code never gets touched if the password is not entered correctly. How much of a difference it makes depends on your PHP code I suppose. The more securely you code, the smaller the difference becomes.